# Swap text with animation upon click

Tags: jquery, css

**CODE:**

```
var loved = false; //set status
    $('a.loveit').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        loved = !loved; // toggles clicked state so false becomes true.
        var heart = $('<i class="icn-heart"></i>');
        if(loved){
                $('.love-text').transition({opacity: 0, scale: 0}, 100, 'easeOutBack', function() {

                 var text = $('div.love-text');
                 text.remove(heart);
                 console.log('remove heart');
                 text.html("<strong>LOVED!</strong>");

                $('.love-text').transition({opacity: 1, scale:1}, 500, 'easeOutBack');
            });
        }
        else{
                $('.love-text').transition({opacity: 0, scale: 0}, 100, 'easeOutBack', function() {

                 var text = $('div.love-text');
                 text.append(heart);
                 console.log('add heart');
                 text.html("<strong>LOVE</strong>");

                $('.love-text').transition({opacity: 1, scale:1}, 500, 'easeOutBack');
            });
        }
```

The scenario is that when **clicking** first time, original "**Love**" swap to "**Loved**". Then when **clicking** second time on same area, it would switch back to original text "**Love**".

I tried this but when clicking on button, text disappeared and then i checked on console saying `"uncaught typeerror: object [object object] has no method ' replace '`. I am not sure what it means. I am also looking through stack overflow and found some that may work but i thought if/else conditional would be a bit easier to understand within my capacity.

Help and pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem. However I can't get it to work because it can't find the function "transition". Which libraries are you using? Can you also provide us with the html or uptdate this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/Xwtav/

Comment: @RononDex - thanks, use transit plugin at http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/. I have update the html in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xwtav/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could fix your problem. I have removed the `text.append(heart);` and `text.remove(heart);`. Also I made sure the dom is loaded before your code executes.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xwtav/5/

Comment: Saw the example, but the problem is that heart icon will be there in original state, then after click, heart icon should be removed and text is changed to "Loved". Then click again, heart icon will be added back to default state and text is changed back to "Love". Is it impossible?

Comment: Yes, check the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xwtav/5/ . I have moved the icon out of your "text" div and used `.toggle()` to hide / show the icon

Comment: saw the example on fiddle. it applies to <i> heart icon right? Give me a few minute to attempt following your example. thanks

Comment: No, I have removed the <i> tag because this has absolutely no effect on images. I replaced it with a div

Comment: attempted with <i> tag because it has a class. it worked fine. One question though - why i cannot declare heart as a variable, i.e. remove(heart)? also next question - is it possible to make two functions which will have these including transition functions? If yes I will attempt again. thanks so much

Comment: You can declare heart as a variable. However this is a bad practise in your case because it complicates things a lot. Especially if you have the icon inside your "text" div. That is why I moved it out of your text div. Simply hidding and showing it again is a lot easier and results in better maintainable code. I don't understand your other question "s it possible to make two functions which will have these including transition functions?"

Comment: I see about declaring heart as a variable being a bad practise. I have a lot more to learn. Thanks for the help :) Toggle seems to be a easy way. I wanted to know if I could put these codes into two functions, i.e. changeLove and originalLove and stuff these into each. then call the functions into if/else conditional. would it be easy to maintain?

Comment: Sure you can do that. However it only makes sense if you need to call that functions from somewhere else too. Until you don't have to do that you should be fine with 1 single function

Comment: @RonnonDex - oh I see so I don't have to create 2 functions for change and original love because it is for only specific page. Got it and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you removing the div containing the text in the onclick handler ?

Please remove this line form the click event function

```
 text.remove(heart);
```

I made the change, here is a demo http://loadmycode.com/build/x1dcI2Xr8/7
Since, i could not find the function .transition() , i replaced it with .animate()

Comment: need to remove heart icon and show "loved" when click on text. Click twice, it will have heart icon and show "love".